# Rendering .md files in html using marked.js

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

I am trying to render a markdown file (`.md`) in a `<body>` component of an html page. I came across [marked.js](https://github.com/markedjs/marked).

The documentation presents the following usage:

```
marked.parse('# Marked in the browser\n\nRendered by **marked**.');
```

Which works well for what I want to do (it renders the markdown in html format). However, I'd like the input into the `marked.parse` call to be a `.md` file such that I don't have to write all of the content between simple quote barriers.

I tried:

```
marked.parse(src='file.md');
```

and

```
marked.parse('href=file.md');
```

but this didn't work.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you using Node.js?

Comment: @JackBashford no... importing via CDN

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late to the party here. Anyway...

I am using marked.js for the flatfile-CMS I am working on.
There, I use PHP for reading the file-contents into a DOM-Object.

```
<div class='md'><?= htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('file.md')); ?></div>
```

From there, it should be as straightforward as the documentation suggests:

```
<script>
let el = document.getElementsByClassName['md'][0];
el.innerHTML = marked.parse(el.innerHTML);
</script>
```

Or for parsing the contents of every '.md' container on the site:

```
<script>
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName['md']).forEach( (el) => {
  el.innerHTML = marked.parse(el.innerHTML);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It just came to me that you could use the JavaScript fetch API instead and keep things fully Client-Side.

```
fetch( 'https://example.com/file.md' )
  .then( response => response.text() )
  .then( (result) => {
    var content = marked.parse(result);
    document.querySelector( '#my-container' ).innerHTML = content;
  });
```

`fetch` is a promise. It grabs the file from the specified URL and uses marked to parse immediately. *(Obviously, change the `querySelector` to select your destination element.)*

Also, you might want to add some error-handling for when the fetch goes wrong.
Like this:

```
...
.then( (response) => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
  }

  return response.text();
})
...
```

I strongly suggest, looking into security here. Depending on what you are trying to do, you might not have control over the file's contents. It's just JS, but still…

You can find more resources about the fetch API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch).