# Is it possible to precalculate javascript with a static output?

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

I've got a fairly simple script, taken from [another question on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72557262/rendering-md-files-in-html-using-marked-js);

```
fetch( 'https://example.com/file.md' )
  .then( response => response.text() )
  .then( (result) => {
    var content = marked.parse(result);
    document.querySelector( '#my-container' ).innerHTML = content;
  });
```

It takes a markdown file, and using marked generates HTML.

My intention is for the site to be static, and it feels like it's a waste doing the conversion every time on the client with Javascript. However, I want some sort of automatic process to convert from the Markdown I'm writing in to the raw HTML.
Initially I thought there might be a preprocessor I could use, but after researching I've not been able to find one that suits my needs.

Since the output of the Javascript will always be the same, is there a way to essentially precalculate or cache the result of this script, generating a static HTML file?

Comment: Using a preprocessor seems like a good fit here. Have you tried that?

Comment: if the result is always the same why don't you just copy the content and use it? If you have a server you can only send the URL being requested I guess

Comment: You could at least cache the md or the resulting html document in localStorage for a while. Fetching an additional text file and stealing the user's computation time is not a huge issue compared to what other websites do (like loading full motion video ads).

Comment: I've been looking at preprocessors, but haven't been able to find one that's simple. They all seem to do far more than I want, or use their own propreitary formats. The reason I don't just convert to HTML and use that directly is it makes editing easier, and managing markdown files is a bit easier than html. I appreciate it's not the worst offence compared to most sites, but I'm wanting to get as fast as possible without making it a chore to manage.